# Why does Hibernate add too many backticks into field names breaking the query?

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am working on a spring-boot application that uses hibernate as its JPA provider. I have had no issues testing it with the in-memory H2 database, but I had to add `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true` to the application.properties when I tried to use the production mysql server since one of the table names is a reserved keyword in mysql.
However, it hibernate now adds extra backticks in the middle of identifiers, causing mysql to reject the query as malformed. Here is such a query:

```
select scorecard0_.`id` as id1_10_3_, scorecard0_.`default_role_`id`` as default_2_10_3_, scorecard0_.`game_`id`` as game_3_10_3_, robotrole1_.`id` as id1_8_0_, robotrole1_.`description` as descript2_8_0_, robotrole1_.`name` as name3_8_0_, robotrole1_.`scorecard_`id`` as scorecar4_8_0_, scorecard2_.`id` as id1_10_1_, scorecard2_.`default_role_`id`` as default_2_10_1_, scorecard2_.`game_`id`` as game_3_10_1_, game3_.`id` as id1_3_2_, game3_.`name` as name2_3_2_, game3_.`type` as type3_3_2_, game3_.`year` as year4_3_2_ from `scorecard` scorecard0_ left outer join `robot_role` robotrole1_ on scorecard0_.`default_role_`id``=robotrole1_.`id` left outer join `scorecard` scorecard2_ on robotrole1_.`scorecard_`id``=scorecard2_.`id` inner join `game` game3_ on scorecard0_.`game_`id``=game3_.`id` where scorecard0_.`game_`id``=?
```

You probably don't need to reed the whole thing, but there are several instances of ``` scorecard0_.`default_role_`id`` ``` and similar, where the `id` in `default_role_id` has been quoted an extra time. Is there a way I can fix this? Or do I need to file a bug report and wait?

Here are the classes for some of the entities in the query:

```
@Entity
public class Scorecard implements Identifiable<Long> {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    private Game game;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST,mappedBy = "scorecard")
    @NotEmpty(groups = {Default.class,Creating.class})
    private Set<ScorecardSection> sections = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "scorecard")
    private Set<Result> results = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST,mappedBy = "scorecard")
    private Set<RobotRole> robotRoles = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private RobotRole defaultRole;

    public Scorecard() {
    }

    public Scorecard(long id){
        setId(id);
    }

    public Game getGame() {
        return game;
    }

    public void setGame(Game game) {
        this.game = game;
    }

    public Set<ScorecardSection> getSections() {
        return sections;
    }

    public List<FieldSection> getFields() {
        return sections.stream().filter(section -> section instanceof FieldSection)
                       .map(section -> (FieldSection) section).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Set<Result> getResults() {
        return results;
    }

    public Set<RobotRole> getRobotRoles() {
        return robotRoles;
    }

    public Set<RobotRole> getRoles() {
        return robotRoles;
    }

    public RobotRole getDefaultRole() {
        return defaultRole;
    }

    public void setDefaultRole(RobotRole defaultRole) {
        this.defaultRole = defaultRole;
    }

    public interface Creating{

    }
}

@Entity
public class RobotRole {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    private Scorecard scorecard;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "robotRole", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<ScoreWeight> weights = new HashSet<>();
    @NotNull
    private String name;
    private String description;

    public RobotRole() {
    }

    public RobotRole(String name){
        setName(name);
    }

    public Scorecard getScorecard() {
        return scorecard;
    }

    public void setScorecard(Scorecard scorecard) {
        this.scorecard = scorecard;
    }

    @AssertTrue
    public boolean weightsMatchScorecard() {
        return weights.stream().map(ScoreWeight::getField)
                      .map(ScorecardSection::getScorecard)
                      .allMatch(scorecard1 -> Objects.equals(scorecard1.getId(), scorecard.getId()));
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Set<ScoreWeight> getWeights() {
        return weights;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**Note:** what Hibernate **should** be doing with this option enabled is converting, e.g. `default_role_id` to `` `default_role_id` ``. what is happening is ``` `default_role_`id`` ```. Notice the extra backticks around `id`. They should not be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in hibernate that is fixed after the Hibernate version I'm using (5.0.9). I'll try to fiddle with version numbers so that I can use a version where this bug is fixed that doesn't conflict with other dependencies.

**EDIT:** the newest version of hibernate that cooperated with spring was 5.0.12,which did not have this bug. I may open a new question about whether/how I can use hibernate 5.1.x or 5.2.x with spring.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is exactly what hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true does.

But since you are having problemas with 1 table, you can use a different solution, like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="\"User\"")
public class User {
    ...
}
```

This will add the backticks just around the table that is a reserved keyword.

Comment: I couldn't get the markup to show correctly in a comment. I'll add a note to the question.